# CRM 2011: How to find out the origin of a trigger for a plugin?

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I need to find out with code in a plugin for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 what was the origin of the trigger that fires the current plugin.

Example: I have a plugin that fires on the update message of a contact. I also have another plugin that fires on the update of a custom entity. In these second plugin, i also do an update of the contact entity. So here i need to know i the contact plugin fires because of a change on the form or because an other plugin called a contact update.

I read about callerorigin for crm 4.0. But that doesn't exist anymore for crm 2011.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a generic way to determine the origin like you want, but a simple solution would be to add a bit field called "UpdatedFromPlugin" to Contact and set that to true when you update the contact from another plugin.  Then in the contact plugin, check that flag.

Comment: I thought of that, i'm giving it a shot now. But this should be implemented by Microsoft not?

Answer (score 5):

Could you not check IPluginExecutionContext's `Depth` property? If called from another plugin if will be 2 (or greater...)